# fire simulation program dont know how to initialize it

Tags: c++

The program is supposed to output a matrix of 12x24 which is bordered by 0s, has 1s in the middle, and a 2 at the location of (1,1) i do not know in which part to initialize M[row][col]=2; because anywhere i put it, it does not output the 2 to the first spot, any suggestions?

```
int main()
{
    int M[N/2][N];
    int ROWS, COLS, row, col;
    int r, c;
    ROWS = sizeof(M) / sizeof(M[0]);
    COLS = sizeof(M[0]) / sizeof(M[0][0]);
    fill(M, ROWS, COLS, 1, 1);
    row=1;
    col=1;
    for(r=0; r< ROWS; r++)
    {
        for(c=0; c < COLS; c++)
        { 
            if (r==0||r ==ROWS-1)
            {
                M[ROWS][COLS]=0;
            }
            else if(c==0||c==COLS-1)
            {
                M[ROWS][COLS]=0;
            }
            else {
                M[ROWS][COLS]=1;    
            }

            cout<< M[ROWS][COLS];
        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    print(M, ROWS, COLS);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by first spot? index (0,0) or (1,1) of the 2d matrix?

Comment: as in M[1][1] so the first spot inside the matrix that is not a 0 of the border

Comment: so you basically needs to find a way to set M[1][1] =2? If so,you can directly do it after your two for loops. You have row and col defined but never used. you can do M[row][col] = 2 after the for loops

Comment: ive tried that but it still outputs a 1 into the first spot instead of the 2

Comment: did you print the first spot inside for loops or in the print function?

Comment: inside of the for loops

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're using `ROWS` and `COLS` as array indices inside the `for` loops...you
probably meant to use the loop variables `r` and `c`.

Also, it's considered bad form to use upper case names for regular variables...the
convention in C is to use upper case identifiers only for macros.

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you write M[1][1]=2; just before the line cout<<M[ROWS][COLS] then you will see the output you want. It is silly to do it that way, because then you will assign that single location (M[1][1]) to the same value repeatedly--to be exact, 288 times--but you cannot print the wrong value for M[1][1] if you set it to the correct value each time you print anything. There are better ways to do it, of course.

You would be much better off to cleanly separate the actions the program performs. There are really two things it must do:

1. Initialize the array.
2. Print the contents of the array.

Each of these actions should be performed by a different function. That is, call one function one time to initialize the entire array, and then call another function one time to print the entire array. This way every cell in the array is set to the correct value before any cell is printed.

If you do this, you should very easily be able to find a good place in your code to set M[1][1]=2 so that you see the correct printout.

I am assuming this is an exercise that will later be extended to do something more with the array, so that it makes sense to use an array in the first place. If so, there is a very good chance you'll have to print the array again at some point, and then you'll be very glad that you wrote a function that prints the array *and does nothing else*.